Which is the correct way to create redirects from existing nodes
I was discussing with a friend who usually makes different redirects on his site.

Having an existing and published Node he creates a new Node of the same Content Type and creates a redirect from the old to the new one, keeping published the old node.
Having an existing and unpublished Node he creates a new Node of another Content Type and creates a redirect from the old to the new one, keeping unpublished the old node.

For the first case what I will do is edit the existing node with the new content and create the redirect from the old URL to the new one.
For the second case what I will do is delete the existing Node, create the new Node, and create a redirect from the old URL to the new one.
I was searching for some documentation on the redirect module page and in Google without luck.
So, in these cases, which will be the correct way to take?

I am afraid is a no black & white answer here and you're both right. It really comes down to your needs, use case and budget.
The redirect module will automatically create that redirect for you if there are changes that affect the path pattern.
Ex: If your pattern is based on page title, [node:title]. A change in the page title will automatically create the redirect.

Having an existing and unpublished Node he creates a new Node of
another Content Type

Why create a new content type and not re-use the exiting one? I would ask. Maybe they realized that those should be a separate content type for whatever reason?

For the second case what I will do is delete the existing Node

Why delete and not edit it and publish? Unless you're also creating a new content type for this one?
Maybe your friend is doing it like that for record keeping purposes. Maybe your friend doesn't have revisions enabled. Maybe the number of nodes are few, but if there were thousands, might rather delete them. Or maybe they have a high budget so they can afford to having a large DB no matter what.
However, assuming your friend always takes that approach for any site. Then you should ask him directly as to why that is. Particularly the creating a new content type part.
In conclusion, "the correct way" will depend on your needs, use case, and budget. Without knowing these, it's hard to say.
